# Add instruction to drop down select box in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, select, helper

I am displaying a list of all users (from a Users model) in my Rails 3 application. In a helper (in this case it's Faults) I have the following:

```
def user_all_select_options
  User.all.map{ |user| [user.name, user.id] }
end
```

In the view I have the following:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, user_all_select_options %>
```

This simply creates a drop down list with the first users name pre-selected as it is at the top of the list. What I am trying to do is add an instruction(?) at the top of the list that is unselectable. The idea is to prevent the top user from getting constantly accidentally set as the required user even when they don't want to be.

So rather than the select box looking like this:

[image: Anthony User]

I would like it to look like this:

[image: Select a user]

Is this possible, if so, how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `:prompt` option.

```
<%= f.select :user_id, user_all_select_options, :prompt => 'Select a user' %>
```

Comment: The app throws an exception when the 'Select a user' is selected and the form is submitted. Can it be validated against to throw an notification to the user?

Comment: Add a `validate_presence_of :user` on your target model.